How to Auto-Size AG Grid Columns to Fit Cell Contents with a Max Width Restriction?
I'm working with AG Grid in JavaScript, and I want to implement the following behavior:
When the grid is first loaded, I want the columns to auto-size based on the content, but with a maximum width restriction.
How can I achieve this?
I'm aware of the fitCellContents option, which adjusts the column size according to the content:
autoSizeStrategy: {
    type: 'fitCellContents'
}

However, according to the Ag Grid documentation, using fitCellContents doesn't allow setting a maximum column width.
Important:

I don't want to use defaultMaxWidth in the column definition since I want users to be able to resize the columns later.




const maxColumnWidth = 150;

let gridApi;

const gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  rowData: null,
  onFirstDataRendered: (params) => {
      params.api.autoSizeAllColumns();

      const columnsWitHigherLimit = params.api.getColumns()
      .filter(column => column.getActualWidth() > maxColumnWidth)
      .map(column => ({key: column, newWidth: maxColumnWidth}));

      params.api.setColumnWidths(columnsWitHigherLimit);
   }
};



ag-gridjavascript

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
